# Apple push notification integration issue

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Before I always had to give push notifications certificates (p12 files) to the server developer, so he could send push notifications to my applications.

But as far as I understand now it's possible to do without these certificates according to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

According to Apple:

*A provider authentication token is a JSON object that you construct, whose header must include:
The encryption algorithm (alg) you use to encrypt the token
A 10-character key identifier (**kid**) key, obtained from your developer account
The claims payload of the token must include:
The issuer (**iss**) registered claim key, whose value is your 10-character Team ID, obtained from your developer account
The issued at (**iat**) registered claim key, whose value indicates the time at which the token was generated, in terms of the number of seconds since Epoch, in UTC*

The question is where to take these **kid, iss, iat** values from the developer account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I've watched the video from WWDC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDBCTvHrix8, it explained almost everything.

1) for **kid** you need to https://developer.apple.com -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> APNs Auth Key -> Press + button -> choose Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production) (it was added not so long ago) -> After you create it, you will see Key ID in this item (new item will appear in APNs Auth Key menu). This is your **kid** value

2) **iss** is your team ID, to take it you need to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers -> App IDs -> Press on any of your App IDs (if you don't have any, you need to create one for your application) -> you will see the details where you will see *Prefix: 8jkjlj2k* . This is your team ID and it will be the same for all your apps in your developer account.

3) **iat** : As far as I understand it's the time when server developer generated the token on his side, so you don't need to provide this value to the server developer